# Work With Webpage node.js

Tags: node.js, module

I need some node.js module for working with webpages.
Which will push button,write smt in input and smt like it.
So can someone help me?

Comment: Please write whole words, by `smt`, do you mean `something`?

Comment: Take a look at PhantomJS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS).